# c#- Json as stream to excel

Tags: c#, json, stream, excelpackage

I have .json files stored in AWS S3 bucket.
I use the function `OpenStreamAsync`to get a specified file and I want to read it and arrange the items according to the way I expect them to be in the .json file but into excel (I use `EEPlus`).

What is the best practice to do so?

Comment: Break this into steps and view each step as unrelated to the others. First, read your JSON into a collection of some objects. Write that code as if it doesn't matter what you're going to do with it next. Separately, write code to write a collection of objects to Excel. For that second part, it doesn't matter where the objects came from - JSON or somewhere else. This isn't really an answer, just a pointer in the right direction. If you separate it into separate problems you can solve them separately. You might already know how to do one, but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }
```

1) create a class that matches your JSON you could use 
   http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public object car { get; set; }
}
```

2) use Json.NET to deserialize

```
Install Package

PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json


Code to serialize JSON
var group2 = JObject.Parse(yourjson).ToObject<RootObject>();
```

3. Create your EEPlus document with your objects